# git: Remove Change-Id for branches

Tags: git, gerrit

I have a git repository which has two remotes, one that enforces Change-Ids and one that enforces to remove them.
I have gerrit's commit-msg hook that creates a Change-Id for every commit.
I also have a hook that for branches with a certain name, Change-Id is not created.
What I want is something that will remove the it without me having to amend each commit manually.
My current work flow:

- Create a commit which gets a Change-Id
- Move to a designated branch
- git am the patches with Change-Ids
- amend each commit and remove Change-Id

Any way to automate the last step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the `Change-Id` line before applying the patch.

```
sed "/^Change-Id: /d" foo.patch | git am
```

In `sed`, `/^Change-Id: /` tries to find the line that starts with `Change-Id:`, and `d` removes the line if it exists. `foo.patch` is not changed. Its content without `Change-Id` is output to stdout and passed to `git am`.

To find the line with a more precise pattern,

```
sed "/^Change-Id:\s\+I[0-9a-f]\{40\}/d" foo.patch | git am
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried adding this to my .config file but couldn't. Suggestions will be welcome.